# Burp suite "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?" error

Tags: proxy, burp-suite

While running burp suite as an intercept proxy on a users computer, I am getting an error in the burp log saying:

```
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I have the certificate installed on the system, and I am able to intercept the traffic, however when the traffic is intercepted the user can no longer get forwarded to the site (using `google.com` or `duckduckgo.com`) it will just hang instead of forward the user. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: What do the log tell you?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox Exactly what I just posted, the burp log says `Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

Comment: Are you using HTTP instead of HTTPS? Or a wrong port?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox I've tried both. How would I check if I'm using the wrong port?

Comment: Was the browser configured with "no proxy" before you used burp? Is burp configured with a proxy under "User options" "Connections" "Upstream Proxy Servers"?

Comment: @Enos I got it figured out. It seems that the connections to my server didn't accept SSL without a self signed certificate, so adding the certificate to Burp fixed it